# get data from json, but my data not array, swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift3

I have respond from json and I want to get it for my variable, but it's no array in respond

```
{
"status": true,
 "msg": "Login berhasil. username=081xxxxxx reg_id=",
"id_user": {
      "no": "349",
      "nama_teknisi": "Putra Utama",
      "telp_teknisi": "081xxxxx"
    }
}
```

I have some code, but still error, this my code:

```
Alamofire.request(URL_USER_LOGIN, method: .get).authenticate(user: username!, password: password!).responseJSON { response in
        if let error = response.error{
            self.hideLoading()
            return
        }
        debugPrint(response.result.value!)
        let parsedResult = JSON(response.result.value!)

        var successed:Bool = true
        if let success = parsedResult["status"].bool{
            successed = success
        }

        if successed {
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                print("success")
                self.hideLoading()
                let id_user = parsedResult["id_user"].array
                for id_item in id_user! {
                    self.lbnama.append(id_item["nama_teknisi"].string!)
                    self.lbtelp.append(id_item["telp_teknisi"].string!)
                    self.keychain.set(self.lbnama, forKey: "nama_key")
                    self.keychain.set(self.lbtelp, forKey: "telp_key")
                    print(self.keychain.get("nama_key"))
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("error")
        }
}
```

and this is my error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
let id_user = parsedResult["id_user"].array
```

to:

```
let id_user = parsedResult["id_user"].dictionary
```

Because your json is returning a Dictionary.

Then you can append to your label.

Comment: it's sooo help meee

Answer (score 1):

`id_user` is a dictionary not array , so

```
let id_user = parsedResult["id_user"].dictionary // dictionaryValue
self.lbnama.append(id_user["nama_teknisi"].string!)
self.lbtelp.append(id_user["telp_teknisi"].string!)
```

Answer (score 0):

From your response it seems that `parsedResult["id_user"]` is not array but dictionary. So you should use:

```
let id_user = parsedResult["id_user"].array
```

But if you are not sure whether `parsedResult["id_user"]` would be array of dictionary, you can handle it like.

```
var id_user: [Any] = []
let idUserObj = parsedResult["id_user"]
if let arr = idUserObj as? [Any] {
    id_user = arr.array
} else if let dict = idUserObj as? [String: Any] {
    id_user = [arr.dictionary]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to get the `parsedResult` as an array, this will result in `id_user` being nil. Hence, the error. 
Since `parsedResult` is a dictionary, as per the json response you have shown above, you need to read `parsedResult` as a dictionary.

Simply change,
`let id_user = parsedResult["id_user"].array`
to
`let id_user = parsedResult["id_user"].dictionary`